# Increment term in Raft algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing, distributed-system, consensus, raft

i'm trying to learn the raft algorithm to implement it, i don't have understood when the term is incremented, apart from when a node pass from stato follower to state candidate there are others cases when the term is incremented? For instance when the leader increment the last commit index? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking from a standpoint of a single peer in the Raft cluster, you will update your term if:

- you receive a RPC request or response that contains a term higher than yours (note here that if you're in the leader mode, you also need to step down as a leader and turn to follower)
- you're in the follower mode and didn't hear from the current leader in the minimum election timeout time (you'll be switching to candidate mode)
- you're in the candidate mode and didn't get enough votes to win the election and the election timeout elapses

Generally observing the system, the term will be increased only when a new election starts.